# Repeated data in concurrent jQuery ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm fetching data from a table of links on a webpage. As I iterate through the table, I kick off a bunch of ajax requests, increment a counter, then `checkFinished()` when I get to the end to see if they're all done.

In the mean time, my ajax requests start finishing - all the urls are different and lead to different content, but the `data` I print out will often be the same! Not all identical, but across 30 requests there might be 6 unique `data` fetched.

```
for (var i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
    //...getting the link
    href = a.attr("href")
    console.log("Fetching"+a.innerText);
    $.ajax({
        url:href
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(href, data); //the data doesn't match the href page!
    })
}
```

I can see that href is different for each call, but data is the same as described.

Crucially, it works perfectly if I add `async: false` to the `$.ajax` call, so something is up with the ajax call.
I've tried messing with other ajax settings with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't be href = a.eq(i).attr("href") ? Anyway there are better way to cycle items, like $.each()

Comment: I replied previously but was deleted for some reason. It previously had `a.eq(0)`, which was correct, but have removed it for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Edit, updated

Try

```
var max = 5;
$("a").slice(0, max).each(function(k, v) {
  console.log("Fetching" + $(v).text());
  $.ajax($(v).attr("href"))
  .done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
})
```

Comment: My comment to kajyr was apparently deleted (?!), but there is no problem with the href. I edited to remove that.

Comment: Thanks but this is essentially identical to what I'm doing. I have no problem with iterating through the `a` tags, my problem is entirely with the data return by the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: Nothing returned by `$.ajax()` ? Tried adding `.fail()` callback to check for error messages ? Are all calls to ajax completing ? Do duplicate data entries appear ? Not certain about requirement ? Could try piece at original post or above at console, this page ; view returned `data`

Comment: I get data, but the data is often duplicated.

Comment: Is possible that some linked `href`'s at page are duplicates ? Could save each requested `url` , or `href` to array , to verify duplicate `href`'s ? Full url's at `href` , or also shortened url's ? Type of expected return data ; image ; full document ; other ? Thanks

Comment: As in the question, I print the hrefs, and know they're unique. They're full documents.

Comment: Not certain how duplicate `data` could be generated ? If possible , could create a jsfiddle to demonstrate issue ? Could be different url's at jsfiddle , same pieces . Thanks